# Mouse coordinates in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, events

What is the difference between these three methods of getting mouse coordinates:

- `[NSWindow convertBaseToScreen]`
- `[NSEvent* locationInWindow]`
- `[NSWindow mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream]`

I already checked the documentation, but the descriptions were too technical. Could someone explain the difference between these three in simpler terms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every window and every view has its own coordinate system, which (unless you've modified it) starts at (0, 0) in the bottom-left and counts up and to the right. `-[NSEvent locationInWindow]` gives you the location where the event took place the window's coordinate system (that is, (0, 0) is the bottom-left of the window). `-[NSWindow convertBaseToScreen:]` takes a coordinate in the window's coordinate system and converts it to screen coordinates, so that (0, 0) now means the bottom-left of the whole screen.

`-[NSWindow mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream]` gives you the location (in the coordinate system of the window you send it to) where the mouse is **right now**, unrelated to any event. This is rarely useful information.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was perfect. Just one thing- you said mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream returns the coordinates of the mouse's position in the window's coordinates. What would happen if the mouse is outside the window though?

Comment: @Farhad: All coordinate systems are basically infinite — they just aren't all visible. For example, if the mouse is two pixels to the left of the bottom of the window, the coordinates are (-2, 0).